# a von Neumann algebra is isomorphic to the tensor product of von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

The slice maps are defined in the above sceenshot.

If we take normal state $\psi$ on $N$, then the slice map $L_\psi$ defined by

$L_\psi(\sum x_i\otimes y_i)=\sum \psi(y_i)x_i$

extends to a normal conditional expectation from $M\otimes N$  to $M$.

Can we choose a special $\psi$ that  make $M\otimes N$ to be  $*$-isomorphic to $M$?

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking. If you just want $M \otimes N \simeq N$, then this has nothing to do with the choice of $\psi$ whatsoever. Do you want $L_\psi$ to be an isomorphism or something?

Comment: Yes. I want $L_\psi$ to be an isomorphism

Comment: Then as in Martin’s answer, that’s really only possible when $N = \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we choose a special $\psi$ that  make $M\otimes N$ is $*$-isomorphic to $N$?

No. For starters, most of the time $M\otimes N$ will not be isomorphic to $N$. You could have $M=N=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and it already fails. Or if you want infinite-dimensional examples, take $N$ amenable, for instance the hypefinite II$_1$-factor, and $M$ a non-amenable II$_1$-factor, or any infinite von Neumann algebra. Then $M\otimes N$ cannot be isomorphic to $N$.

A conditional expectation is a projection, which is about the farthest you can have an isomorphism. They are not multiplicative, and they are not injective. Note that as $\psi$ is a linear functional, it will always have a significant kernel, so the slice map cannot be injective, and it can only be multiplicative if $\psi$ is, which again is something you won't usually have.